# ajax 400 bad request

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Im using some javascript to create a node

```
var dto=new Object();
dto.name='abc';

 var jsonString=JSON.stringify(dto);
 $.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',  
  url: '/MyTool/tree/createNode',  
  data: jsonString,  
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  mimeType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(dto) {  

  }  
 });
```

i print the data and i get {"name":"abc"}

and passing data to my controller

```
@Controller
public class TreeController {

public class TestDTO implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/tree/createNode", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody TestDTO createNode(@RequestBody final TestDTO testDTO) {
    return testDTO;
}
```

}

Im getting over and over again ajax error "400 Bad Request ".

Ive tried like 100 links in google and nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL are not matching.

In javascript : '/MyTool/createNode',
In Java : "/tree/createNode"